# What is the correct way to structure an object representing a Rubric

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, t-sql, data-structures

I have a [Rubric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubric_%28academic%29) entity that I need to represent in my application. I have created an implementation but unfortunately my gut feels like the data structure I've created is flawed (for example I cant see a 'good' way to represent it relationally).

Note that the functionality of the data structure must allow for an arbitrary amount of columns (and column headings) to be added to the rows.

Basically I have 2 questions, firstly is there some way to structure this object so that it can be persisted relationally to a standard SQL database or is serialization my preferred option?

Secondly is there a better approach to representing this structure than what I have used regardless of the answer to the first question? I'm pretty sure there is and I just can think of it...

Thanks in advance for any input

[image: Rubric]

My current representation. Which will be mapped back to a C# class (I'm just building the client side first)

```
var Data = {
    ColumnsHeaders: [{ name: "Beginning", value: 1 },
                        { name: "Developing", value: 2 },
                        { name: "Accomplished", value: 3 },
                        { name: "Examplary", value: 4}],
    Rows: [{
        Description: "Stated Objective or Performance",
        Columns: [{ text: "Description of identifiable performance characteristics reflecting a beggining level of performance", value: 1 },
                    { text: "Description of identifiable performance characteristics reflecting movement toward a mastery of performance", value: 2 },
                    { text: "Description of identifiable performance characteristics reflecting a mastery of performance", value: 3 },
                    { text: "Description of identifiable performance characteristics reflecting a high level of performance", value: 4}]
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your second question, how about a structure like this?

```
var rows = [
  {
    name: 'Stated Objective or Performance'
    columns: [
      {
        name: 'Beginning',
        value: 1,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...'  
      },
      {
        name: 'Developing',
        value: 2,
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    // another row
  }
];
```

Comment: Yep, good catch I should have mentioned. I thought of this and maybe it still makes more sense but then I am duplicating the header for every row right? (Which is why I settled on my approach at the time but looking it now urs seems much more readable)

Comment: Yeah, I guess, but you when you print out the HTML you can check if there's already a header and just append the data to that column. What's your HMTL like, a table?

Comment: Oh that side of things isn't an issue, I was thinking more from the data side (in terms of storing redundant data). Yeah exactly, its a html table element...

Comment: I don't see a problem with duplicating that info. With your structure you have to duplicate the `value` as opposed to using a more obvious relationship by header name.

Comment: Yep, fair enough, I think you're right. Thanks allot for your input, much appreciated.